# Angular 2 *ngIf for 'this'

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 2 I have this **component.html**:

```
<li *ngFor="let something of somethings">
   <span>{{something}}</span>
   <input class="doit" type="text" *ngIf="iscalled" />
<div id="container">
     <button class="btn btn-warning editsection (click)="editAction()">Edit</button>
</div>
</li>
```

with this **component.ts**:

```
editAction(){ this.iscalled = true; }
```

`iscalled` is, by default, set to false in my component.

Basically, for each `something` of `somethings` I produce, along with my list is an input field that is assigned to it, and a button that runs `editAction()`. The button is only there if the user clicks on the `editAction()` button.

Now, as is, clicking on the `editAction()` button will enable all input fields in my list. I would like to restrict this to the exact `li` element that it is meant for.

I don't know if Angular 2 has a specific action for this, or if this is a plain javascript solution.

Comment: Have you considered using the index that ngFor exposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: with this setup don't set **default value** of **iscalled** to **false**

```
<li *ngFor="let something of somethings">
     <span>{{something}}</span>
     <input class="doit" type="text" 
            *ngIf="something.iscalled" />       //<<<===changed

     <div id="container">
          <button class="btn btn-warning 
           editsection 
           (click)="editAction(something)">     //<<<===changed
              Edit
           </button>   
     </div>
</li>
```

---

```
editAction(something){ something.iscalled = true; }
```

if you want to **toggle** it then you can do following,

```
editAction(something){ something.iscalled != something.iscalled; }
```

Comment: thanks for this! however, the toggle option does not seem to work. and i understand that there's a typo on yours, so it's not like i'm copy-pasting it. the logic ends up doing nothing.

Comment: it should work. I'm pretty sure about it. If you are using any model for `something` object than make sure to add iscalled property to that model. It will work as expected.

Comment: I see. if it doesn't work you can change `something.iscalled!=something.iscalled` to `something.iscalled=!something.iscalled`